# sqlstates42000 Syntax error or access violation: 1075

Tags: sql, laravel-5.5

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto colu
  mn and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `tbl_category` (`cat_id` int not null, `cat_name` varchar(50)
   not null, `cat_detail` varchar(100) not null, `cat_img` varchar(50) not null, `menu_id` int not null auto_incremen
  t primary key, `parent_id` int not null auto_increment primary key, `cat_update` timestamp not null, `created_at` t
  imestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

```
Schema::create('tbl_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('cat_id')->NOTNULL;
            $table->string('cat_name',50);
            $table->string('cat_detail', 100);
            $table->string('cat_img', 50);
            $table->integer('menu_id', 11)->NOTNULL;
            $table->integer('parent_id', 11)->NOTNULL;
            $table->timestamp('cat_update')->NOTNULL;
             $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Help me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to create a table with auto increment and primary key properties in two columns (menu_id and parent_id):

```
menu_id int not null auto_increment primary key, parent_id int not null auto_increment primary key
```

You'll have to choose only one column, and I guess (by the table name), it should be cat_id.

As of [this docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables), I guess you can change the definition of cat_id to:

```
$table->integer('cat_id')->autoIncrement()...
```

or

```
$table->increments('cat_id')...
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i have problems how to write it on migration to migrate of laravel

Comment: @Hondahoda you're welcome. I've updated the answer with docs and ways of declaring auto_increment pk. Could you accept the answer if the question is resolved, please?

Answer (score 0):

my code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTblCategoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbl_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('cat_id')->PRIMARYKEY->NOTNULL;
            $table->string('cat_name',50);
            $table->string('cat_detail', 100);
            $table->string('cat_img', 50);
            $table->integer('menu_id', 11)->NOTNULL;
            $table->integer('parent_id', 11)->NOTNULL;
            $table->timestamp('cat_update')->NOTNULL;
             $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_category');
    }
}
```